# Products are not displaying less than 100

Tags: magento-2.1

I'm trying to display products which are less than rs:100  using product list widget, but it is showing error. Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance,
[image]

Result is like this :

[image]

Comment: please check exception.log or system.log

Comment: Nothing is there in those log related to this issue.

Comment: Enable display_errors  from bootstrap file and check if any error display

Comment: If i gave price as equal to 100 then it is showing the products .